# Can Windows Sharepoint Services be integrated with a ASP.NET MVC Content Management System?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sharepoint, wss

I want to build a CMS with asp.net but I'd like to use something things with WSS.  I have things like document approval that I'd like to build because I read WSS can handle workflows.  Don't know how to do it, haven't got a clue, but I know I'd like to implement it.  If I build a CMS around asp.net mvc, is wss something I can just have on one of the pages in my cms or does wss "stuff" have to be in all its own set of web pages?

Also, what about a php site, obviously on windows, instead of asp.net?

Thanks for any thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest I have seen is a site where SharePoint was used to edit pages but a standard ASP.NET application was used for display, using the SharePoint API to get data from the SharePoint pages library - any process running on a server in the SharePoint farm can use the full SharePoint API, though I wouldn't want to try it outside of .Net.

A similar approach would work for a full CMS app storing data in SharePoint, but it seems like more work than it would be worth - SharePoint is great when you need SharePoint features with a little customization, but if you need complete customization it usually just gets in the way.

Answer (score 1):

Almost all of the utility of sharepoint can be accessed via web services, so in general, yes. However for some of them you have to be on the local machine, so that can limit you.

Comment: what do you mean about the local machine?

Comment: Some web services can only be accessed by processes running in the same environment as Sharepoint.   So you wouldn't be able to call them if your process was running remotely or on another machine.  (Machine in the most generic sense, not sure how it'd work with clustering)

Answer (score 0):

This all depends on what you mean by "integration".   Its really easy to share a database with another application.

Comment: I don't really know what I mean yet either.

Answer (score 0):

If your only goal is to use the workflow features, might I suggest you browse MSDN for the WF(workflow foundation) articles. The sharepoint workflow is built on workflow foundation and most of the additional features simply extend workflow foundation to work hand in hand with other features in sharepoint such as task delegation and automation, info path form integration and much more. Without using these other features you aren't gaining anything over just the windows workflow foundation.

Brian